# JavaMail with Apache James mail server

Tags: java, apache, email, ssl, jakarta-mail

I have an apache james mail server hosted on a local machine. It uses a self signed certificate which I added to the trusted list. I am trying to send and receive mails using java mail

I get this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

The SSL debug output however says that a trusted certificate is found. Otherwise it doesn't tell me much. I should also mention that this mail server works with openssl as well as with thunderbird.

Code for the receiving of mails:

```
    String host = "192.168.1.21";
    Boolean debug = true;

    POP3Folder folder = null;
    Store store = null;
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.host", host);
        props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3s");
        props.put("mail.pop3s.port", "995");

      Session session = Session.getInstance(props,null);
      session.setDebug(debug);

      store = session.getStore("pop3s");
      store.connect(username, password);
```

The exception is thrown when I attempt to connect.

I have been banging my head against the wall for the last couple of hours/days so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The SSL debug output:

```
Info:   ***
Info:   Found trusted certificate:
Info:   [
[
Version: V3
Subject: CN=192.168.1.21, OU=private, O=private, L=pretoria, ST=gauteng, C=za
Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
modulus:  22201738425808301357843951429131863923295077691776461029270738957881925042102429206972015246280434827640419315658812269457485815395646018000726167885520466978079051879949885421741485411500412697981582621030362804785391242469536810788864680524659094190388912471585546967116467038492937424356023436763640787748242238829212068970215212531761712168559272937198654805596431568611192706600640030995533703350490664304506975658770991265086884832523665903150599863152070395170101007238711948275224105410201713594276436919539183706721126654808927498591115057177598201458589477257783098334024997797269658976390073190289972335957
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Thu May 01 13:28:37 CAT 2014,
           To: Wed Jul 30 13:28:37 CAT 2014]
Issuer: CN=192.168.1.21, OU=private, O=private, L=pretoria, ST=gauteng, C=za
SerialNumber: [    618a1f7d]
Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 90 DF D4 14 E8 B7 70 38   28 F0 7F CC 83 60 3E 98  ......p8(....`>.
0010: DC EB 0B D5                                        ....
]
]
]
Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
Signature:
0000: 13 42 F1 F0 FB C4 A4 AD   1B 93 96 CE 53 64 72 4A  .B..........SdrJ
0010: D2 C5 C7 66 18 BA 07 A6   C3 C6 97 9F E4 D1 8B 6F  ...f...........o
0020: B9 72 3C F6 1C 3F 98 FB   3C 6C 74 A3 20 83 99 9A  .r<..?..<lt. ...
0030: 9D 91 41 32 59 71 63 4A   3B 84 2E 2D 72 9F 2D AA  ..A2YqcJ;..-r.-.
0040: 83 84 56 78 19 F9 8A AF   DD 11 D5 C5 21 9E 93 06  ..Vx........!...
0050: 4D 48 2D 22 12 1F DA 1F   40 6A AD 9A 9A 29 4F 52  MH-"....@j...)OR
0060: 2D EB EB A7 13 B9 27 11   35 94 02 25 4E DF E5 6C  -.....'.5..%N..l
0070: 6B 12 79 DD 22 E9 BB FE   20 34 4F B4 A1 CE E2 14  k.y."... 4O.....
0080: EE A4 B4 A8 D5 2D 9F 80   82 5E 71 03 49 B3 30 3C  .....-...^q.I.0<
0090: 56 06 E3 62 2E 1C 5A E4   EE 15 4A 03 77 1C 94 4C  V..b..Z...J.w..L
00A0: 20 D7 47 95 62 7F 21 22   CB 64 BF A0 34 D6 D5 AD   .G.b.!".d..4...
00B0: 57 C1 A3 AD 69 70 DB 32   A5 B6 38 BB 1F 00 C7 5A  W...ip.2..8....Z
00C0: 3A 73 3B 8D EE 2E A8 40   9A 24 D0 58 5C D5 A4 2D  :s;....@.$.X\..-
00D0: 0F 09 2E DB 84 CF 55 21   79 C8 22 B5 2D E7 91 51  ......U!y.".-..Q
00E0: 05 8A 7D 1A 19 25 CC 30   EC 9B BA 77 78 9E 2E C9  .....%.0...wx...
00F0: 6C 2D F3 47 E9 44 1E 5A   41 92 14 11 9B E4 8E 59  l-.G.D.ZA......Y
]
Info:   *** ServerHelloDone
Info:   *** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
Info:   http-listener-1(2), WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
Info:   SESSION KEYGEN:
Info:   PreMaster Secret:
Info:   0000:
Info:   03 
//infos continue with things in between like  CONNECTION KEYGEN: etc
//many more things like this
//continued
http-listener-1(2), WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
Info:   *** Finished
Info:   verify_data:  {
Info:   121
Info:   ,
Info:   89
//many more infos

Info:   }
Info:   ***
Info:   http-listener-1(2), WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
Info:   http-listener-1(2), READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
Info:   http-listener-1(2)
Info:   , RECV TLSv1 ALERT:
Info:   fatal,
Info:   handshake_failure
Info:   %% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
Info:   http-listener-1(2), called closeSocket()
Info:   http-listener-1(2), handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal   alert: handshake_failure
```

Comment: This is doing a *re-handshake* for some reason right at the end. Do you know why? Is the server asking for a client certificate for example? Can you get this same SSL trace for the server side?

Comment: @EJP - doesn't the handshake alert mean there's no shared cipher suites (if it were SSLv3 vs TLS, then it would be a protocol alert). The server might have RSA key transport disabled. Maybe ephemeral exchanges with RSA signing: `SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` or `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`

Comment: @jww The first handshake got to the ChangeCipherSpec message, which is a success. My question is why the re-handshake.

Answer (score 2):

How exactly did you add the certificate to the "trusted list"?

Have you seen [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert)?

You can also try setting the [mail.pop3s.ssl.trust property](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html) to "*" or to the name of your server.

BTW, in your code, you don't need to set mail.store.protocol or mail.pop3s.port.  The former is not needed because you pass the protocol name to the getStore method explicitly.  The latter is not needed because it's the default for the "pop3s" protocol.

I checked with a JSK SSL expert, who had this to say:

There is so much missing from this log, it's hard to tell what's really gone on.

There seems to be a problem with the decrypt/de-pad/de-MAC operation on the server side.

They took out the most important byte (second) of the RSA Premaster Secret:

```
Info:   PreMaster Secret:
Info:   0000:
Info:   03
```

If I had to guess, I would suggest trying:

```
java -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.rsaPreMasterSecretFix=true App
```

then switch to false.

Other comments:

EJP seems to think this is a rehandshake, the only hint is "Session-2".  There could have been a second handshake on this connection, but those are usually only done in the case of asking for Client Authentication, but there is no CertificateRequest between the Certificate and the ServerHelloDone, so probably not that.

This could very likely be just the second separate connection made by this process.

This has nothing to do with trust, the handshake wouldn't proceed past the ServerHelloDone if that didn't succeed.

In the case of any handshake, the client sends the ChangeCipherSpec, then the next packet is a Finished packet with verify_data which is encrypted using the just negotiated keys (48 bytes = 4 Header + 12 verify_data + 20 MAC + 12 padding).  If the server can't decrypt/de-pad(AES-CBC)/de-MAC properly, then it will send back a handshake_failure, which seems to be the case.

There seems to be a problem with that decrypt/de-pad/de-MAC operation. The problem could be on the server side (most likely), or perhaps they put in a replacement provider on the client side?

Comment: On your first question. I am using it as part of a JEE application hosted in Glassfish4. I added the certificate to the cacerts.jks keystore in domains/domain1/config. According to glassfish docs this is where it stores the list of trusted certificates (I also tried  mail.pop3s.ssl.trust property with no luck). I used to get the error mentioned in that FAQ but since I added the certificate to that keystore the SSL log says that the certificate is trusted. Then  passes around keys(I think that is what it is doing) and then complains about the handshake.

Comment: Note: [there is nothing named "JEE"](https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE), the correct name is "Java EE".  I don't understand why you're getting that exception.  It doesn't seem to be related to "trust".  It's the JDK that does all the SSL handling so I would check your JDK configuration for possible problems.  Maybe just reinstall the JDK to see if that helps?  Can you post the SSL debug output?

Comment: It's just a force of habit to use JEE as an acronym for Java EE. I will try reinstalling the JDK. If the problem persists I will post the SSL debug output since at the moment I am busy reinstalling things to see if it maybe solves the issue.

Comment: I added the SSL debug log. I also tried this on another PC with similar results. This leads me to believe that I am doing something wrong. I just don't know what.

Comment: I'm stabbing in the dark here, but....  It kind of looks like the server is unhappy with something the client is sending.  You might want to try enabling more debugging on the server side and see what it says.  Maybe it requires a newer version of TLS?  Try setting mail.pop3s.ssl.protocols to "TLSv1.2".

Comment: I tried adding the protocols. It did not fix the problem. It now recieves this error javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error. I will look at the servel logs again. I will also find out how to enable the debugging on the server side and check that out

Comment: The evidence for the re-handshake is ChangeCipherSpec, 'Finished', the new session, 'TLSv1 Handshake', ...